# Automate multiple SOQL Count() query in Excel

Tags: soql, excel

I have to query multiple soql COUNT() queries on different objects. Is there any way or tool to automate the task ?

For example, in Excel I will paste all the queries in one column and it will query one by one and paste the result count in next cell.

[image]

I don't want to install anything on my office laptop and in Excel I don't want to convert those soql to Power Querry.

How can I use excel to easily login to specific salesforce org and run the queries ???

Comment: https://www.salesforceben.com/excel-to-salesforce-connector-in-depth-review/ ??

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally able to query from Excel using Salesforce CLI. Though I have to install this tool but it's free and developed by Salesforce.

This Post helped me [Link](https://terencechiu.com/2016/08/24/querying-salesforce-records-via-excel-using-force-com-cli/).

My VBA code after installing Salesforce CLI. Now I can write and select multiple SOQL to execute and paste success and error in same excel file.

```
Sub SOQL_execute()

Dim pathToForceCli As String
pathToForceCli = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value

Dim sCmd As String

Dim oShell As Object
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        
Dim oExec As Object
Dim oOutput As Object
Dim oError As Object

Dim str As String

Dim cel As Range
Dim selectedRange As Range

Set selectedRange = Application.Selection

For Each cel In selectedRange.Cells
    If Not IsEmpty(cel.Value) Then
        sCmd = pathToForceCli & " data query --query " & Chr(34) & cel.Value & Chr(34)

        'execute Salesforce cli command
        Set oExec = oShell.Exec(sCmd)

        'Store stdout and stderr stream
        Set oOutput = oExec.Stdout
        Set oError = oExec.StdErr

        str = ""

        While Not oOutput.AtEndOfStream
            str = str & vbCrLf & oOutput.ReadLine
        Wend
        
        cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = str
        
        str = ""
        
        While Not oError.AtEndOfStream
            str = str & vbCrLf & oError.ReadLine
        Wend
        
        cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = str

    End If
Next cel

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a custom solution using **LWC** and **Apex**:

1. Build a `.csv` file with the two columns Query and Count and load it in Static Resource
2. Create an Apex Class with two methods - one to read the Static Resource content and another to run the SOQL Aggregate queries.

**Apex Methods**

```js
  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
  public static String readStaticResource(String resourceName) {
    String resourceContent = '';
    StaticResource resource = [
      SELECT Body
      FROM StaticResource
      WHERE Name = :resourceName
    ];
    if (resource != null && resource.Body != null) {
      resourceContent = resource.Body.toString();
    }
    return resourceContent;
  }
```

```js
  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
  public static AggregateResult aggregateQuery(String query) {
    AggregateResult result = Database.query(query);
    return result;
  }
```

3. Create an LWC component and in the HTML add a button. On click of the button read the static resource content and call the query method for each query in the csv. Based on the query result, update the count in the csv and finally download the csv file with updated count values.

**LWC - Javascript**

```js
  async handleClick() {
    const result = await readStaticResource({ resourceName: 'CSV_File' });
    const array = result.split('\r\n');
    const results = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
      const query = array[i]
        .slice(0, array[i].lastIndexOf(','))
        .replace(/(^"|"$)/g, '');
      console.log(query);
      if (query) {
        results.push(this.callQueryMethod(query));
      }
    }
    const aggregateResults = await Promise.all(results);
    console.log('aggregateResults', JSON.stringify(aggregateResults));
    for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
      const query = array[i].slice(0, array[i].lastIndexOf(','));
      if (query) {
        const count = aggregateResults[i - 1]?.expr0;
        array[i] = query + ',' + count;
      }
    }
    const csvContent = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + array.join('\r\n');
    const encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
    let element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', encodedUri);
    element.setAttribute('download', 'CSV_updated.csv');
    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
    document.body.removeChild(element);
  }
  
  async callQueryMethod(query) {
    try {
      const result = await aggregateQuery({ query: query });
      console.log('callQueryMethod', result);
      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('error in callQueryMethod');
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly answering the coding question, but in case other people need this and don't want to spend a week to write their own code: [XL-Connector](https://www.xappex.com/knowledge-base/installing-enabler/), [XL-Connector 365](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104382023?src=office&tab=Overview), and [G-Connector](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/gconnector_for_salesforce/971770431958) all have this feature built-in as a custom formula:

[image]